# Objective-C 2D arrays

Tags: objective-c, arrays

In objective C how can I add specific numeric values to an array at given points (for example row3 column6) And how can I then also retrieve that value to compare it to another array at that same given point? When I try using examples I found online I get memory leaks so how do you all initiate them? What's the probably allocating / deallocating methods, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Objective c is a super set of c so you can follow all the same rules of c programming for declaring and using arrays. ARC (if using ios5) will not manage the memory for these objects because they are not objective c objects so you'll have to manually allocate and destroy the objects yourself. This tutorial should get you started:

http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson8.html